# Error setting property 'externals' message on SVN Commit

Tags: svn, github, commit, svn-externals, externals

I've added svn:externals for a project in subversion, hosted on github. But when I attempt to commit the project I get the following message:

Error Commit failed (details follow):
Error At least one property change failed; repository is unchanged
Error Error setting property 'externals';
Error Could not execute PROPPATCH

I tried both committing with command line and with SVNX. I tried propedit-ing the svn:externals with vim and adding a new line at the end. No luck.
This is the first time I use svn:externals. Any idea?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Jeremy

Comment: Error Could not execute PROPPATCH - Take a look at the server log, it should show you more detailed error description. If you are running SVNServer under Apache, it will be Apache log. If you are running VisualSVN Server, it writes all log messages to the Windows Event Log.

Comment: I am using github as SVN server and SVNX as client (on a mac). How can I read the server logs?

Comment: As issue might be github related (since github does not natively support SVN, but uses Subversion bridge) edit your question and add github info in it. Also, include "github" tag.

Comment: Done. Thanks!
Is there a way to get the svn logs on github then?

Comment: I guess github doesn't support SVN externals, because Git doesn't have a similar concept (git submodules are something different).

Comment: That would kind of make sense, but I cannot find any information mentioning that limitation. And the error message is not saying that at all. Is there any way to make sure of that assumption?

Comment: I sent a message to github support to make sure but they don't answer.
Anybody has tried it before?

Answer (score 1):

I sent a message to github support to make sure and they confirmed that they don't support svn:externals, so that is probably the reason for the error.

So I might find another host, as externals would be extremely useful for me.

Now, if anybody has information about how to access the github svn server logs, I would be interested, as I might have been able to figure it out myself.

Thanks